# Cant update the csv table into phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I get an error which uploading the csv file having different number of "filled" columns as compared to number of column titles in the database

error is this:

```
Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1.
```

When i try to import it with the headings (titles of columns), it works. Else it doesnt work at all.

I dont want to add columns while importing as i am just updating the chosen values of the columns.

I want to update the table now and then.

Comment: Off the top of my head: you can create a temp table and import CSV into it, and then update your original table using `UPDATE` as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13512209/1076075 or you can create SQL file from CSV (with `UPDATE`) using something like this: http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm and then import it using phpmyadmin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916095/invalid-field-count-in-csv-input-on-line-1-phpmyadmin